# Sort Swift Array of Dictionaries by Value of a Key

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to sort a Swift array which is composed of dictionaries.  I have prepared a working example below. The goal is to sort the entire array by the "d" element in the dictionaries. I have prepared this working example which can be placed into a Swift project:

```
var myArray = Array<AnyObject>()
var dict = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()

dict["a"] = "hickory"
dict["b"] = "dickory"
dict["c"] = "dock"
dict["d"] = 5

myArray.append(dict)

dict["a"] = "three"
dict["b"] = "blind"
dict["c"] = "mice"
dict["d"] = 6

myArray.append(dict)

dict["a"] = "larry"
dict["b"] = "moe"
dict["c"] = "curly"
dict["d"] = 2

myArray.append(dict)

println(myArray[0])
println(myArray[1])
println(myArray[2])
}
```

This results in the following output to the log:

```
{
    a = hickory;
    b = dickory;
    c = dock;
    d = 5;

}
{
    a = three;
    b = blind;
    c = mice;
    d = 6;
}
{
    a = larry;
    b = moe;
    c = curly;
    d = 2;
}
```

The goal is to sort the array by the "d" element, so that the above output would be changed to the following (which is based on numerical order of "d": '2, 5, 6'):

```
{
    a = larry;
    b = moe;
    c = curly;
    d = 2;
}
{
    a = hickory;
    b = dickory;
    c = dock;
    d = 5;
}
{
    a = three;
    b = blind;
    c = mice;
    d = 6;
}
```

There are some other questions that seem similar, but when you look at them, it becomes clear they are not addressing this. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To declare, if you need to keep it as AnyObject, you have to explicitly cast:

```
var myArray = Array<AnyObject>()
var dict = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()

dict["a"] = ("hickory" as! AnyObject)
dict["b"] = ("dickory" as! AnyObject)
dict["c"] = ("dock" as! AnyObject)
dict["d"] = (6 as! AnyObject)

myArray.append(dict as! AnyObject)

dict["a"] = ("three" as! AnyObject)
dict["b"] = ("blind" as! AnyObject)
dict["c"] = ("mice" as! AnyObject)
dict["d"] = (5 as! AnyObject)


myArray.append(dict as! AnyObject)

dict["a"] = ("larry" as! AnyObject)
dict["b"] = ("moe" as! AnyObject)
dict["c"] = ("curly" as! AnyObject)
dict["d"] = (4 as! AnyObject)

myArray.append(dict as! AnyObject)
```

Without appending, you can do it like this:

```
var myArray: [AnyObject] = [ ([
    "a" : ("hickory" as! AnyObject),
    "b" : ("dickory" as! AnyObject),
    "c" : ("dock" as! AnyObject),
    "d" : (6 as! AnyObject)
  ] as! AnyObject), ([
    "a" : ("three" as! AnyObject),
    "b" : ("blind" as! AnyObject),
    "c" : ("mice" as! AnyObject),
    "d" : (5 as! AnyObject)
  ] as! AnyObject), ([
    "a" : ("larry" as! AnyObject),
    "b" : ("moe" as! AnyObject),
    "c" : ("curly" as! AnyObject),
    "d" : (4 as! AnyObject)
  ] as! AnyObject)
]
```

Which gives you the same result. Although, if only the value object in the dictionary needs to change, you don't need to cast the elements of the array:

```
var myArray: [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] = [[
    "a" : ("hickory" as! AnyObject),
    "b" : ("dickory" as! AnyObject),
    "c" : ("dock" as! AnyObject),
    "d" : (6 as! AnyObject)
  ], [
    "a" : ("three" as! AnyObject),
    "b" : ("blind" as! AnyObject),
    "c" : ("mice" as! AnyObject),
    "d" : (5 as! AnyObject)
  ], [
    "a" : ("larry" as! AnyObject),
    "b" : ("moe" as! AnyObject),
    "c" : ("curly" as! AnyObject),
    "d" : (4 as! AnyObject)
  ]
]
```

Then, to sort, you use the sort() closure, which sorts an Array in place. The closure you supply takes two arguments (named $0 and $1), and returns a Bool. The closure should return true if $0 is ordered before $1, or false if it comes after. To do this, you've got to cast an awful lot:

```
//myArray starts as: [
//  ["d": 6, "b": "dickory", "c": "dock", "a": "hickory"],
//  ["d": 5, "b": "blind", "c": "mice", "a": "three"],
//  ["d": 4, "b": "moe", "c": "curly", "a": "larry"]
//]

myArray.sort{
  (($0 as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["d"] as? Int) < (($1 as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["d"] as? Int)
}

//myArray is now: [
//  ["d": 4, "b": "moe", "c": "curly", "a": "larry"],
//  ["d": 5, "b": "blind", "c": "mice", "a": "three"],
//  ["d": 6, "b": "dickory", "c": "dock", "a": "hickory"]
//]
```

Comment: No, this did not work. It resulted in an error: Cannot find an overload for 'sorted' that accepts an argument list of type '(Array<AnyObject>,(_,_) -> _)'
Are you able to try this in XCode to see if your idea works?
Update: Wait, I tried using the entire block of code you provided which also includes updated array declaration. The error disappeared, but the sort did not work. I got: [b: dickory, a: hickory, c: dock]
[b: blind, a: three, c: mice]
[b: moe, a: larry, c: curly]

Comment: Yeah you've got to change the declarations like I've got above. `var myArray = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()
var dict = Dictionary<String, String>()
`

Comment: Please read previous reply which I updated. The error disappeared, but the sort did not work. I pasted your code directly into XCode along with println(myArray[0])
println(myArray[1])
println(myArray[2]) and got: [b: dickory, a: hickory, c: dock] [b: blind, a: three, c: mice] [b: moe, a: larry, c: curly]

Comment: The last line should be `myArray.sort() {$0["c"] < $1["c"]}` or `var newArray = sorted(myArray){$0["c"] < $1["c"]}`. Sorted creates a new array, whereas, sort does not.

Comment: The last line is a statement that returns what I've put in the comment - I'll change it a bit to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks doisk. It seems we're really close here. The problem is that I am not free to change the original "var myArray = Array<AnyObject>()
var dict = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()" to your new "var myArray = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()
        var dict = Dictionary<String, String>()"  This is because the real world program I am working on requires AnyObject. In fact the actual dictionary element I am sorting by is an Int

Comment: Thanks. I have also updated the original sample code. What do you think?  Does it work for you?

Comment: Doisk - thank you for hanging in there. Works great. You certainly don't have to, given that you have put some time into here already - but would you have any further advice or perspective to offer in your answer on WHY this works? (and another thought is... to be helpful to others,  I am guessing your answer can be edited to remove the intermediate tries and just leave the final answer... just a thought)  Thank you again!

Comment: Very useful. Thanks

Comment: `Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' operands`

Answer (score 17):

**Sort Array of Dictionary in Swift 3 & 4**

```
let sortedResults = (userArray as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
```

Comment: not work very well if you have key values like 1, 2, 10, 100 etc

Answer (score 9):

edit/update: **Xcode 11 • Swift 5**

```
var array: [[String:Any]] = []
var dict: [String: Any] = [:]

dict["a"] = "hickory"
dict["b"] = "dickory"
dict["c"] = "dock"
dict["d"] = 5

array.append(dict)

dict["a"] = "three"
dict["b"] = "blind"
dict["c"] = "mice"
dict["d"] = 6

array.append(dict)

dict["a"] = "larry"
dict["b"] = "moe"
dict["c"] = "curly"
dict["d"] = 2

array.append(dict)
```

---

```
let sortedArray = array.sorted { $0["d"] as? Int ?? .zero < $1["d"] as? Int ?? .zero }

print(sortedArray)  // "[[b: moe, a: larry, d: 2, c: curly], [b: dickory, a: hickory, d: 5, c: dock], [b: blind, a: three, d: 6, c: mice]]"
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift

```
let mySortedArray = myArray.sorted(by: {(int1, int2)  -> Bool in
    return ((int1 as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "d") as! Int) < ((int2 as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "d") as! Int) // It sorted the values and return to the mySortedArray
  }) 

print(mySortedArray)
    
myArray.removeAllObjects() // Remove all objects and reuse it
    
myArray.addObjects(from: mySortedArray)
    
print(mySortedArray)
```

it is easy to arrange the array of dictionary value in ascending order.  It doesn't need any loops.

Answer (score 1):

when we parse the data then we can sort by using NSSortDescriptor

```
let dataDict1 = responseDict.valueForKey("Data")
self.customerArray = dataDict1!.valueForKey("Customers") as! NSMutableArray

var tempArray = NSMutableArray()
for  index in self.customerArray {
   tempArray.addObject(index.valueForKey("Customer") as! NSMutableDictionary)
}

let descriptor: NSSortDescriptor =  NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector: "caseInsensitiveCompare:")
let sortedResults: NSArray = tempArray.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor])
self.customerArray = NSMutableArray(array: sortedResults)
```